# Hyperplane Separation of point and cone

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, metric-spaces

Let $X$ be $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and $M$ is a subspace of $X$ and $x_0 \notin M$ and let $K$ be a cone without the origin ($K$ may not be convex and for any $x \in K$, $-x \notin K$). I wonder whether there exists a continuous linear function $f$ on $X$ such that $f$ is $f = 0$ on $M$, $f(x_0) \ne 0$ and $f \geq 0$ on $K$.
I think we need to use one kind of hyperplane separation theorem to separate cone and point. But I have no idea what the exact theorem is. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible. Take $X=\mathbb R^2$, $M= span(e_1)$,
$K=\mathbb R^+ e_2 \cup \mathbb R^+ (e_1-e_2)$. Then any functional $f$, that is zero on $M$ is of the form $f(x) = \pmatrix{ 0 \\f_2} ^T x$. In order to have $f\ge0$ on $K$, $f_2=0$ is necessary, as $f(e_2) = f_2$ and $f(e_1-e_2) =-f_2$.

Comment: Excellent... How do you come up with it?

Comment: This is my try for another problem. However, you prove that my way is wrong. Could you please see another post of my original [problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481977/non-uniqueness-of-linear-function-extension-with-cone-positiveness)