# Non-uniqueness of linear function extension with cone positiveness

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

Let $M$ be a proper linear subspace of $\mathbb R^n,$ and let $K$ be a cone in $\mathbb R^n$ without the origin ($K$ may not be convex and for any $x \in K$, $−x \notin K$). Suppose $f:\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R$ is linear and $f>0$ on $K.$ Fix $x_0 \notin M$. Does there exist a linear $g: R^n \to \mathbb R$ such that $g>0$ on $K,$ $g= f$ on $M,$ and $f(x_0) \ne g(x_0)?$

This is a companion problem of my other [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3481881/hyperplane-separation-of-point-and-cone?answertab=oldest#tab-top). That problem is my try for this problem. However, my attempt was proved to be false in the post. So I asked this problem here. Could anyone help me?

Comment: Clearly $K$ is contained in the half space $\{f>0\}.$ Are you allowing $K$ to have limit points in $\{f=0\}?$

Comment: As $K$ is a cone (but delete the origin), clearly $K$ has a limit point in ${f \ne 0}$

Comment: Right, OK (although you meant $\{f=0\}).$ Can $K$ have any nonzero limit points in $\{f=0\}?$

Comment: Yeah.. My fault. I mean $\{ f = 0\}$. We can construct a linear function that $K$ has a nonzero limit point in $f = 0$. I can only prove that in the special case $K=\left\{ \left(x_{1},x_{2},\cdots,x_{n}\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}:x_{i}\geq0\text{ for all }i\text{ and }x_{i}>0\text{ for some }i\right\} $, this statement is true. But for any $K$, I have no idea.

Comment: For $K$, the only conditions are $K$ is a cone without origin and if $x \in K$, then $-x \notin K$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counterexample: In $\mathbb R^2,$ let $K=\{(x,y):y>0\},$ $M=\{(x,x): x\in \mathbb R\}.$ Let $f(x,y)=y.$ Then $f>0$ on $K.$ Suppose $g$ is linear and $g>0$ on $K$ and $g=f$ on $M.$ Because $g>0$ on $K,$ $g(x,y)=cy$ for some $c>0.$ Because $g=f$ on $M,$ we have $g(1,1)=c=f(1,1)=1.$ Therefore $c=1,$ hence $g=f$ everywhere.

Comment: Excellent Answer. Thanks very much!